# What's the derivative wrt. $x$ of $\int_0^x f(x-s)\,ds$?

Tags: derivatives

I know how to compute the derivative of $f(x-s)$ and by the fundamental theorem of calculus the derivative of $\int_0^x f(s)\,ds$ is $f(x)$. But I can't figure out how to do it when they're mashed together as in $\int_0^x f(x-s)\,ds$. The presence of the $s$ inside $f(x-s)$ prevents me from factoring out $f$ and using the product rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\;dt = f(x,b(x))b'(x) - f(x,a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)\;dt$$ and get $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(x-t)\;dt = f(0)+\int_0^xf'(x-t)\; dt.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way is by a change of variable, which is also essentially how one prove the Leibniz formula mentioned by @spaceisdarkgreen . Take $u = t/x$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\int^x_0 f(x-t)\ dt = \int^1_0 xf(x(1- u))\ du.
\end{align}
Taking the derivative with respect $x$ gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_0 f(x-t)\ dt =&\ \int^1_0 f(x(1-u))\ du+ \int^1_0 xf'(x(1-u))(1-u)\ du.
\end{align}
Using integration by part formula, we get
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 xf'(x(1-u))(1-u)\ du =&\ - f(x(1-u))(1-u)\big|^1_{u=0} - \int^1_0 f(x(1-u))\ du\\
=&\ f(x) -\int^1_0 f(x(1-u))\ du
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int^x_0 f(x-t)\ dt = f(x).
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) for noticing a massive simplification I missed and not gloating about it.